# Pass parameters to a $.doTimeout function in a for

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, settimeout

This, will log '7' seven times after 1 second.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $.doTimeout(1000, function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

But how to do if I want it to log '0','1','2','3','4','5','6' ?

($.doTimeout is the [Ben Alman's plug-in](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/), but I think it's the same problem with setTimeout.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $.doTimeout(1000, function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }(i));
}
```

You need to associate a scope to the variable `i` so that when the closure looks it up it gets the value from that scope.

Comment: YEAH! I tried to associate a scope, but to the $.doTimeout function itself, not to put it in. Thank you so much!